# How to get sentence from embedding vector with Universal Sentence Encoder?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, word-embeddings

I'd like to ask, if there is possibility to get sentence (or word) from embedding vector using [Universal Sentence Encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3)?

First of all, I've clustered my embedded sentences and I've got a vector which is representing center of the cluster, and now I want to convert this to some sentence which will have the best meaning for this specific cluster.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run the universal sentence encoder in reverse. There is no practical way to take an arbitrary embedding vector and get a sentence.

My suggestion would instead be to find the sentence in your data with the embedding closest to your center. [Euclidean distance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html) works well, specially if you used K-means or another euclidean method to create your clusters.

Comment: This answer is fine, but searching is not the only way. You could add that in principle, another component could be trained to generate sentences given a sentence embedding. This is basically what happens in machine translation systems, and also some sentence embedding systems are trained in this way (there is a decoder component that generates sentences that is used only for training).

Comment: You are right, training a decoder from scratch to reverse the USE would be a possible method. Still not feasible, but definitely worth mentioning. I mostly wanted to suggest the practical advice in my second paragraph and did not think it through enough. Thank you for adding.